# JQuery: Hide second video when page loads, then display second video when first finish to play

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

Sorry in advance as I am not really skilled with JQuery! I am trying to upload 2 videos on a page with these conditions: First video plays automatically when page loads, second video is hidden when page loads and appears when first video finishes to play.
Here is what I have done (knowing that I can't even make the second video disappear :/):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Coding Test 3</title>
<script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('video#vid2').hide();

    $('video#vid1').bind('ended', function() {
       $('video#vid2').show()
       $('video#vid2').play();
        }
    })

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <header>    
            <h1>Backin' Up</h1>
        </header>
    <section>
            <p>The Backin' Up Song started with an interview on Kansas TV station KMBC in which a woman describes witnessing an attempted robbery at a Shell gas station.</p>
            <p>Autotune the News appropriated the video to produce "Backin' Up Song" which creates a song from the witness's description of events.</p>
            <div class="videoWrapper">
                <video id="vid1" controls autoplay>
                    <source src="videos/backinupsong.mp4">
                    <source src="videos/backinupsong.ogv">
                </video>
            </div>
            <p>"Backin' Up Song" was subsequently covered by Canadian indie band Walk Off the Earth. You can watch it below when the original has finished playing.</p>
            <div class="videoWrapper">
                <video id="vid2" controls autoplays>
                    <source src="videos/wotebackinupsong.mp4">
                    <source src="videos/wotebackinupsong.ogv">
                </video>
            </div>
        </section>

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help is welcome! Thanks a lot!

Comment: do you want to hide the first video when it finishes too?

Comment: looks pretty valid, are you sure jQuery is loaded correctly? I am not sure it did

Comment: Please check browser console if any error there?

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your code a bit, and I'm using pure Javascript, instead of jQuery, take a look:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  document.getElementById('vid1').addEventListener('ended', function() {
    var vid2 = document.getElementById('vid2');
    vid2.classList.remove('hidden');
    vid2.play();
  });
});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Video</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <header>
      <h1>Backin' Up</h1>
    </header>
    <section>
      <p>The Backin' Up Song started with an interview on Kansas TV station KMBC in which a woman describes witnessing an attempted robbery at a Shell gas station.</p>
      <p>Autotune the News appropriated the video to produce "Backin' Up Song" which creates a song from the witness's description of events.</p>
      <div class="videoWrapper">
        <video id="vid1" controls autoplay>
          <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
      <p>"Backin' Up Song" was subsequently covered by Canadian indie band Walk Off the Earth. You can watch it below when the original has finished playing.</p>
      <div class="videoWrapper">
        <video id="vid2" class="hidden" controls>
          <source src="http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4">
        </video>
      </div>
    </section>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

As you can see, it's working the way you expect, so you only need to change the video sources to your videos, and it will probably work for you too! :)

Answer (score 0):

You have **syntax error** in your `code`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('video#vid2').hide();
    $('video#vid1').bind('ended', function() {
       $('video#vid2').show()
       $('video#vid2').play();
        }//this here is causing error which is invalid too. Remove this
    })

});
```

Rest everything looks fine.

A suggestion I would like to add. From **[this source](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)**,

> **As of jQuery 1.7, the [<kbd>`.on()`</kbd>](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the
>   [<kbd>`.bind()`</kbd>](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) method is used for attaching an event handler directly to
>   elements. Handlers are attached to the currently selected elements in
>   the jQuery object, so those elements must exist at the point the call
>   to [<kbd>`.bind()`</kbd>](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) occurs. For more flexible event binding, see the discussion
>   of event delegation in [<kbd>`.on()`</kbd>](http://api.jquery.com/on/) or [<kbd>`.delegate()`</kbd>](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/).**